# Access synced notes from iPhone on Windows other than through Mail/Outlook?

Tags: windows, sync, iphone, windows-mail, apple-notes

I see from the [iPhone how to page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/how-to/index.html) that synced notes on Windows appear in MS Mail or Outlook/Outlook Express. I don't use any of these programs. Can I access the iPhone notes some other way? I don't see indication on Apple's site that such a thing is possible. I would like to do this without a 3rd party iPhone application, and I'd really like to avoid MS Mail/Outlook.

For what it's worth, this is for my wife and she's using Windows. I sync my iPhone with a Mac. She's loathe to use a bunch of different programs.

Comment: Fair enough about not wanting to use Outlook, so I've deleted my answer. I think you're painting yourself into a corner though since your options are a bit limited. I know on the Mac there is an app to browse the iPhone called PhoneView - http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/ I don't know if there is a Windows equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present time with the built in apps and iTunes? No. I agree that the fact that it can't sucks.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is using a third party note application, like Evernote that syncs to a web service and then is available on your PC via browser (or with Evernote a PC application).  I'm not thrilled with how Evernote works on the iPhone at the moment, but maybe it will get better.  I've also used Notebook from appigo.com and sync'ed it with toodledo, but I don't usually use the web based note interface for it.